# import sqlite3.dll from from another file location python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, sqlite

I new to python but how do I import the sqlite3.dll file from a custom file location as I can't find anything about it. I can accept any option including building a new pyd,dll,etc file.

Edit:
I need it to be in a separate location.

Comment: Just copy you `sqlite3.dll` file to your Python's installation over the same named file (e.g., `C:\Python\DLLs\sqlite3.dll`)

Comment: However, I need the sqlite3.dll file to be in a separate location

Comment: If you don't want to keep a copy of the file, then use a link to that file and place the link in the expected Python directory.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following answers the above question with more thorough steps.

I had the same issue as administrative rights to the default python library is blocked in a corporate environment and its extremely troublesome to perform installations.

What works for me:

1. Duplicate the sqlite3 library in a new location
2. Put in the latest sqlite3.dll (version you want from sqlite3 web) and the old _sqlite3.pyd into the new location or the new sqlite3 library. The old _sqlite3.pyd can be found in the default python library lib/DLLs folder.
3. Go to the new sqlite3 library and amend the dbapi2.py as follows: Change "from _sqlite3 import *" to "from sqlite3._sqlite3 import *"
4. Make sure python loads this new sqlite3 library first. Add the path to this library if you must.